# maven install throw "error in opening zip file" only after the second try

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, log4j, slf4j

I try to run maven install on my project with some dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

the first time I run `mvn install` it's run just fine (BUILD SUCCESS) 
but the second time ("after I make some changes in the code") I try to run `mvn install` and maven throw "error in opening zip file".

```
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\javax\jms\jms\1.1\jms-         1.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\com\sun\jdmk\jmxtools\1.2.1\jmxtools-1.2.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\com\sun\jmx\jmxri\1.2.1\jmxri-1.2.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\0.9.24\logback-classic-0.9.24.jar; error in opening zip file
```

**but**

if I remove 
log4j,
slf4j,
and logback-classoc
dependencies 
run maven install (BUILD SUCCESS)
return 
log4j,
slf4j,
and logback-classic
dependencies 
run maven install it run just fine (BUILD SUCCESS).

What can be the problem?

**Update:**

well I delete all my .m2/reposetory folder delete all target folder in my project 
then I run `mvn install` and I get

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building d 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.7.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.7.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.7.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.7.1.pom (10 KB at 28.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.7.1/surefire-2.7.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.7.1/surefire-2.7.1.pom (10 KB at 40.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/18/maven-parent-18.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/18/maven-parent-18.pom (24 KB at 74.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/8/apache-8.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/8/apache-8.pom (14 KB at 43.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.7.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.7.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.7.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.7.1.jar (29 KB at 50.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom (5 KB at 21.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.jar (23 KB at 40.8 KB/sec)
[WARNING] The POM for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.24 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ d ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ d ---
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/1.0/maven-toolchain-1.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/1.0/maven-toolchain-1.0.pom (4 KB at 7.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.pom (805 B at 3.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-1.8.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-1.8.1.pom (4 KB at 11.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.18/plexus-components-1.1.18.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.18/plexus-components-1.1.18.pom (6 KB at 20.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/2.0.7/plexus-2.0.7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/2.0.7/plexus-2.0.7.pom (17 KB at 57.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.pom (6 KB at 10.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.pom (713 B at 3.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.pom (710 B at 3.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.8.1/plexus-compilers-1.8.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.8.1/plexus-compilers-1.8.1.pom (2 KB at 3.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.jar (20 KB at 39.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.jar (6 KB at 10.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.jar (13 KB at 12.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to D:\projectsWorkspace\connectingtopostgresdbtests\d\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.5.2\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\0.9.24\logback-classic-0.9.24.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.3.2.GA\hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-annotations\3.4.0.GA\hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.3.0.ga\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.4.0.GA\hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\postgresql\postgresql\9.1-901.jdbc4\postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar; error in opening zip file
[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.573s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 02 17:00:13 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project d: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.5.2\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\0.9.24\logback-classic-0.9.24.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.3.2.GA\hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-annotations\3.4.0.GA\hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.3.0.ga\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.4.0.GA\hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\Idan\.m2\repository\postgresql\postgresql\9.1-901.jdbc4\postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExceptio
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to clean up your local repository (`.m2\repository`) and see if the problem remains.

Comment: It doesn't look as if your attempt to delete the repository was successful. Try again and make sure the broken files aren't there before re-running maven.

Answer (score 4):

step1.

Clean your `.m2\repository` or delete your specific folders from the `.m2\repository` directory

step2.

run `mvn clean install`

step3.

be sure that your internet connection is working fine at the time of running this command, some times it fails due to connection problems.

Comment: `mvn clean compile package install` that's double redundance. package includes compile and install includes package. When you start maven with a lifecycle phase, it will also execute all phases before that phase. So actually `mvn clean install` is equivalent to your command. See the [Maven Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

Comment: Thanks, Sean I removed the useless things

Answer (score 3):

In my case It was giving below error

> error: error reading
>   C:\Users\ppatel4.m2\repository\org\apache\xalan\xalan\2.7.
>   1\xalan-2.7.1.jar; error in opening zip file

Below are the steps I did to fix it.

1. Manually download xalan-2.7.1.jar
2. Remove all files of: ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/
3. Copy the jar which is manually downloaded into the location: ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/

---

```
$ cp xalan-2.7.1.jar ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/
```

Its Done… Try to execute your mvn clean install command.

Comment: I fix the problem by downloading and replacing the jars. hope that help as this answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue just now. Changing maven compiler plugin version to 3.1 helped.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to an incorrect connection url in your maven plugin. 
I was using a vpn connection earlier and hence, it had initialized it with that url which was not valid anymore.

rm -rf {PATH to .m2}/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/

This should fix it